# Last arguments appear corrupted when calling native function

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke, dllimport

Working on a C# wrapper for a native (C) library. I have the following function prototype in the native library:

```
typedef struct _NativeObj *       NativeObj;
typedef struct AnotherNativeObj * AnotherNative;

__declspec(dllimport) NativeObj createNativeObj (
    AnotherNative * anotherNative,
    FirstCallback   firstCallback,
    void *          firstOpaque,
    SecondCallback  secondCallback,
    void *          secondOpaque,
    ThirdCallback   thirdCallback,
    void *          thirdOpaque,
    const char *    firstString,
    const char *    secondString,
    const char *    thirdString,
    time_t          timeout,
    char *          fourthString,
    int             firstInt,
    int             secondInt,
    int             thirdInt,
    int             fourthInt,
    char *          fifthString,
    int             fifthInt,
    char *          sixthString);
```

This is the declaration in the C# code:

```
public delegate int ThirdCallbackDelegate(...);

public const uint NO_TIMEOUT = 0;

private uint   timeout   = NO_TIMEOUT;
private string fourthString;
private uint   firstInt  = 0;
private bool   secondInt = false;
private bool   thirdInt  = true;
private bool   fourthInt = true;
private string fifthString;
private bool   fifthInt  = false;
public string  sixthString { get; set; }

[DllImport("path\\to.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr createNativeObj(
    IntPtr                 anotherNative,
    FirstCallbackDelegate  firstCallback,
    IntPtr                 firstOpaque,
    SecondCallbackDelegate secondCallback,
    IntPtr                 secondOpaque,
    ThirdCallbackDelegate  thirdCallback,
    IntPtr                 thirdOpaque,
    string                 firstString,
    string                 secondString,
    string                 thirdString,
    int                    timeout,
    string                 fourthString,
    int                    firstInt,
    int                    secondInt,
    int                    thirdInt,
    int                    fourthInt,
    string                 fifthString,
    int                    fifthInt,
    string                 sixthString);
```

And the logic behind the parameters:

```
IntPtr myOpaque = createNativeObj(IntPtr.Zero,
            null,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            null,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            thirdCallbackDelegate,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            firstString,
            secondString,
            thirdString,
            (int)timeout,
            fourthString,
            (int)firstInt,
            Convert.ToInt32(secondInt),
            Convert.ToInt32(thirdInt),
            Convert.ToInt32(fourthInt),
            fifthString,
            Convert.ToInt32(fifthInt),
            sixthString);
```

At runtime, right at the native function's start, the values for the arguments after timeout are corrupted.

Comment: Why don't you use StringBuilder instead of String ?

Comment: If you meant that for fifthString and sixthString, they're actually const char * type. I'm trying to correct that, but my company's DLP solution makes it very hard for me to edit the question...

Comment: It seems I declared `time_t` wrong. It's `typedef`'d to `long` in my our code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, using MS tools, and assuming that you did not define `_USE_32BIT_TIME_T`, the `time_t` type is 8 bytes wide. Which means you need to declare it as `long` in your C# p/invoke code to match.

Comment: Thanks, it's actually explicitly `typedef`'d in some header file in this case.

Comment: Er, if your time_t is your own type, then there's not a whole lot we can do to help you. Unless we can agree on what these types are, you are on your own.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your native library isn't using the __cdecl calling convention but something like __stdcall. In general it's best to not take any chances and enforce a calling convention at the native library level instead of letting the compiler or the project options determine it. Try this:

```
[DllImport("path\\to.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
```

Comment: That didn't help, I see now that more than the last pair are passed incorrectly.

Comment: @Oliver If the native function was `__stdcall`, it would be declared as such. The lack of a calling convention in the native code means it is `__cdecl`.